# Get wrong result after converting byte array to String and back in Java

Tags: java

I got a chain of workers that work with byte array, but they have to receive and translate String and char array to the work method `work(@NotNull Object data, @NotNull Object prev)` as well. So I convert byte array in one worker to String `nextWorker.work(new String(result, "UTF-16BE"),this);` and translate it to another worker in work method where it converts back to byte array `if(data instanceof String){workingData = ((String)data).getBytes("UTF-16BE");}`, but result is wrong in some cases ( i pass byte arr size of N and get after byte arr size of N - 2 or something like that, and missed bytes are not from the beginning or ending of that array). Can anybody help me to solve this problem or give advise why it happens.

```
byte[] result = new byte[]{0, 0, 0, 97, 63, -44, 55, -19, 51, 16, -39, -106, 0, 0, 0,
                18, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 63, -32, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32, 63, -84,
                113, -57, 28, 113, -57, 28, 114, 63, -84, 113, -57, 28, 113, -57, 28,
                115, 63, -84, 113, -57, 28, 113, -57, 28, 100, 63,
                -84, 113, -57, 28, 113, -57, 28, 117, 63, -84, 113, -57, 28, 113,
                -57, 28, 108, 63, -84, 113, -57, 28, 113, -57, 28, 109, 63,
                -84, 113, -57, 28, 113, -57, 28, 111, 63, -68, 113, -57, 28, 113, -57, 28, 0};
        byte[] result2 = new byte[]{0, 0, 0, 115, 63, -29, -103, 75, 42, 114, -97, 67, 0, 0, 0, 18, 0,
                0, 0, 11, -1, 63, -84, 113, -57, 28, 113, -57, 28, 0, 63, -36, 113, -57, 28, 113, -57, 28,
                32, 63, -84, 113, -57, 28, 113, -57, 28, 112, 63, -84, 113, -57, 28, 113, -57, 28, -2, 63, -84,
                113, -57, 28, 113, -57, 28, 114, 63, -84, 113, -57, 28, 113, -57, 28, 101, 63,
                -84, 113, -57, 28, 113, -57, 28, 105, 63, -84, 113, -57, 28, 113, -57, 28, 76, 63,
                -84, 113, -57, 28, 113, -57, 28, 109, 63, -84, 113, -57, 28, 113,
                -57, 28, 111, 63, -84, 113, -57, 28, 113, -57, 28, 0};

        try {
            Object data = new String(result, "UTF-16BE");
            byte[] workingData = ((String)data).getBytes("UTF-16BE");
            Object data2 = new String(result2, "UTF-16BE");
            byte[] workingData2 = ((String)data2).getBytes("UTF-16BE");
            System.out.println( Arrays.equals(result,workingData));
            System.out.println( Arrays.equals(result2,workingData2));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre], including sample data, expected output and actual output.

Comment: result = [0, 0, 0, 97, 63, -44, 55, -19, 51, 16, -39, -106, 0, 0, 0, 18, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 63, -32, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32, 63, -84, 113, -57, 28, 113, -57, 28, 114, 63, -84, 113, -57, 28, 113, -57, 28, 115, 63, -84, 113, -57, 28, 113, -57, 28, 100, 63, -84, 113, -57, 28, 113, -57, 28, 117, 63, -84, 113, -57, 28, 113, -57, 28, 108, 63, -84, 113, -57, 28, 113, -57, 28, 109, 63, -84, 113, -57, 28, 113, -57, 28, 111, 63, -68, 113, -57, 28, 113, -57, 28, 0] - byte array.

Comment: workingData = [0, 0, 0, 97, 63, -44, 55, -19, 51, 16, -1, -3, 0, 18, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 63, -32, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32, 63, -84, 113, -57, 28, 113, -57, 28, 114, 63, -84, 113, -57, 28, 113, -57, 28, 115, 63, -84, 113, -57, 28, 113, -57, 28, 100, 63, -84, 113, -57, 28, 113, -57, 28, 117, 63, -84, 113, -57, 28, 113, -57, 28, 108, 63, -84, 113, -57, 28, 113, -57, 28, 109, 63, -84, 113, -57, 28, 113, -57, 28, 111, 63, -68, 113, -57, 28, 113, -57, 28, 0] - byte array after operation. All operations are listed in question. There are literally nothing, else.

Comment: Please [edit] your question, and with an [mre] we mean actual executable code, not just fragments. And from a quick scan, both arrays you posted in the comments are identical.

Comment: I added  minimal reproducible example, and it shows that arrays are different after all. workingData missing 2 bytes.

Comment: Thanks for the MCVE. It looks like the first difference between the two are at index 10 (-39 in `result`). Could it be that this sequence is invalid or possibly have multiple representation in UTF16?

Answer (score 0):

Changing encoding from `UTF-16BE` to `UTF-16LE` solves the problem in the given example.

```
    String data = new String(result, StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE);
    byte[] workingData = data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE);
    System.out.println(Arrays.equals(result, workingData)); // true
```

Is there a reason for `UTF-16BE` encoding to preferred?

Comment: Yes, it is set as standard encoding for char and String in my task. Of course if nothing will work, i ll try to change it.

Comment: And it turned out that StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE fix encoding for result byte array, but now it fails for result2 byte array

Comment: @DmitriiKamianskii If standard encoding types (`UTF_16BE`, `UTF_16LE` etc.) do not work in all situations, it is worth to look at the byte array supplier code or its specification instead of guessing or "fixing" your parser for every set of new data that doesn't fit to it.